# reallocating memory in efficient way

Tags: c++

A new, presumably larger block, can be obtained and initialized with the old block, and then the old block 
be freed.

```
purpose of that code ; reallocating the old memory area with new size

typeName is  Object 

Object *oldArray = objects ; // objects is pointer to old data block 
objects = new Object[ newCapacity ] ;
for ( int k = 0; k < theSize ; k++ ) 
    objects [k] = oldArray [k] ;
... // some other thing 
delete [] oldArray ;
```

Are there any other way to do that job, **efficiently** ?

Comment: What do you perceive as inefficient about your code? The amount of code you've had to write, or the performance of that code?

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? What's the big picture?

Comment: Hmm... standard C++ answer - why are you not using `std::vector`? These sort of problems have already been addressed, why re-invent?

Comment: vector uses std::allocator, and uses placement new.

Comment: @Muggen: is the OP taking us to be muggles for this kind of question? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::vector<Object>`. It will do this automatically for you.

Comment: @fatai: then please enlighten me with the internal workings of vector, if you are so sure. And regarding who gave upvotes for me, let me tell you its none of your business.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to ask yourself is do you need to reallocate at all. Do you need a contiguous buffer?

Yes, `std::vector` will implement it for you but if you don't actually have to have a contiguous buffer you can use `std::deque` which will not reallocate and will potentially use our memory resources more efficiently.

The next thing you should consider is the cost of copying the objects compared to swapping them. That depends totally on the implementation of your objects. (If a swap requires 3 assignments it is obviously not as efficient, but if copies are deep it is likely that swap is more efficient).

Note: `std::deque` will not reassign at all so no need to worry about it if this is what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom allocators like object pools or memory arenas, where you pre-allocate chunks off the heap and then divide them out according to a custom strategy.

Comment: vector and deque already do that too although it reuses memory, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes this operation can be made more efficient.  When this logic migrates to C++0x, it can be made *vastly* more efficient for many important use cases.  `vector` encapsulates this logic, and the most efficient techniques.  Is your quest to learn how vector does it?  If so, ask that, and I'd be happy to explain.